# Как трансформировать список одинарных массивов в список чисел?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

У меня есть список:

```
list_ = [array([1]), array([2]), array([3])]
```

Как мне трансформировать его в:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для NumPy arrays:

```
new_list = [elem[0] for elem in list_]
```

---

*Обьяснение:*

Каждый элемент списка `list_` является полем с одним элементом, который мы из него вытащим индексом `[0]` в генераторе списка.

Comment: Зачем `.tolist()`? `numpy.array` умеет в индексы.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, ой, вы прав, спасибо, я упростил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

еще один, чисто "нампаевский" вариант:

```
res = np.array(list_).ravel().tolist()
```

---

результат:

```
In [9]: res
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3]
```